# I am getting all the sentences continously after sorting the words of sentences but i want one sorted sentence than next below it

Tags: java

my input is -

> who i am
>   what you are

output is -

> am are i what who you

but i want output as -

> am i who 
>   are what you

my code is-

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println("enter the value of n");

    int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> words_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean once_entered = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lines.add(i, scan.nextLine() + " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String word = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < lines.get(i).length(); j++) {
            char char_0 = lines.get(i).toLowerCase().charAt(j);
            if (char_0 >= 'a' && char_0 <= 'z') {
              word += char_0;
              once_entered = false;
            }
            else if (!once_entered) 
            {
                words.add(word);
                word = "";
               once_entered = true;
            }       
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        boolean contains =false;
        for(int j=0;j<words_2.size();j++){
            if(words_2.get(j).contentEquals(words.get(i)))
                contains=true;
            break;
        }
        if(!contains)
            words_2.add(words.get(i));
    }

    Collections.sort(words_2);
   // System.out.println(words_2.size());
   for (int i = 0; i < words_2.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print( " " + words_2.get(i));

    }

    scan.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: What is `n` supposed to be? The number of lines?

Comment: yes, n is number of lines.

Comment: Are you trying to remove duplicates? What is `once_entered`?

Answer (score 0):

Keep putting the input in array of string, iterate and do this. I won't write whole of the code, this is a kind of pseudocode to guide you but yes it has the sort function.

1) Split the sentence with `space`

2)  Sort the array of string using  `Arrays.sort`

```
 String[] dataArray= stingValue.split(" ");
 Arrays.sort(dataArray);
```

3) You can `concat` again via an iteration

Comment: I did this only...i just want  "enter " after every sorted sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void doSome4Bro() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the value of n");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(n);
        ArrayList<String> newLines = new ArrayList<String>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            lines.add(i, scan.nextLine());
        }
        scan.close();

        for(String line:lines){
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            Arrays.sort(words);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line.length());
            for(String word: words){
                if(word.isEmpty())
                    continue;
                if(sb.length() > 0){
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
                sb.append(word);
            }
            String newLine = sb.toString();
            newLines.add(newLine);
        }

        System.out.println("Get some:");
        for(String line: newLines){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you help me to retrieve database column author name and apply this code to sort the names of database column. for eg author names are like-Bertwell; Dale E. (Denver, CO), Markham; Joseph P. (Arvad, CO)  
 
 Bouadma; Noureddine (Gentilly, FR)

Comment: if you have a SQL storage you can use ORDER BY keyword to sort query result

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println("enter the value of n");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());


        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        //0. remove and Move  below

        boolean once_entered = true;

        //1..remove & move below
        //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //}
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             lines.add(i, scan.nextLine() + " ");
             ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
             ArrayList<String> words_2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            String word = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < lines.get(i).length(); j++) {
                char char_0 = lines.get(i).toLowerCase().charAt(j);
                if (char_0 >= 'a' && char_0 <= 'z') {
                  word += char_0;
                  once_entered = false;
                }
                else if (!once_entered) 
                {
                    words.add(word);
                    word = "";
                   once_entered = true;
                }       
            }
        //} //2.comment

        for (int t = 0; t < words.size(); t++) {
            boolean contains =false;
            for(int j=0;j<words_2.size();j++){
                if(words_2.get(j).contentEquals(words.get(t)))
                    contains=true;
                break;
            }
            if(!contains)
                words_2.add(words.get(t));
        }

        Collections.sort(words_2);
       // System.out.println(words_2.size());
       for (int t = 0; t < words_2.size(); t++) {
            System.out.print( " " + words_2.get(t));

        }

        System.out.println("");
     } //3.movded to here
        scan.close();   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are over-complicating the problem or you don't know the tooling that is available to you. There are collections that sort the objects as you enter them.

The logic I can see is

1. Read the number of lines
2. For each line

   1. Split the words
   2. Sort the words
   3. Print

I am really not following the whole three separate lists and doing lowercasing on characters and stuff, so I rewrote this version.

Quick explanation on that "there are collection that sort objects" statement:
A `TreeSet`, and based on the `once_entered` variable, you maybe are trying to remove duplicates? If so, a  `Set` is a perfect data-structure.

```
class Driver {

    private static String strJoin(Iterable<String> lst, String delimeter) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : lst) {
            sb.append(s).append(delimeter);
        }

        sb.setLength(sb.length() - delimeter.length());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void rearrangeLine(String line) {
        // split the words & sort the words
        Set<String> words = new TreeSet<String>();
        words.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s+")));

        // Print
        String output = strJoin(words, " ");
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // read the number of lines
        System.out.println("enter the value of n");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()); 

        // for each line   
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(">> ");
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            rearrangeLine(line);
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

**I/O**

```
enter the value of n
2
>> who i am
am i who
>> what are you
are what you
```